# Server error when entering a percent symbol in search?

Tags: xss, encoding

Fuzzing a website and came across an odd behavior. The site has a search bar, it sends queries via a `GET` request with the standard `?q=` parameter. When I try the standard XSS payloads such as `<script>alert(1);</script>` I get a 403 error.

When I type a percent symbol in the search bar it just sanitizes it to `?q=%25` however when I enter the percent sign in the URL directly it doesn't seem to sanitize it (e.g. `?q=%`).

When I send this query to the server it responds with an error page saying `Uh-oh! We've got a problem on our end.` When I enter `%00` directly in the URL it gives me a page back with a blank search term.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

`%` in the URL is the start of a URL encoded character - see [Wikipedia: Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for details. If you just enter a single `%` it is an invalid encoding which might explain the error page you see. If you enter `%00` it means a character byte 0 (i.e. `\000`, `\0`, `\x00` for typical notations of this "character"). This gets likely interpreted/sanitized as an empty search term since it does not contain any actual printable characters.